# Please help me fix my intestine

Tags: jigsaw-puzzle, packing

Due to some unfortunate events involving a teleporter and a ceiling fan I had my innards spread all over the place.

Interestingly my intestine was split into equal sized chunks representing all the shapes you can get by assembling straight and curved segments.

[image]

Please help me fix my intestine by fitting all pieces back in my ventral cavity depicted below.  They must form a single contiguous path as is required by proper digestion.  The loose ends can be anywhere.

You can rotate or flip over the parts.  They are body parts after all.  But you cannot change the natural shape of the segments.

[image]  [image]

Comment: Rot13(Gur sbhegu cvrpr ba gur zvqqyr ebj qbrf abg pbaarpg gb nal bgure jvgubhg pnhfvat n oybpxntr fb vg zhfg unir orra shegure znathyngrq. Ohg vs guvf bar pna or gjvfgrq ba vgfrys cerfhznoyl nal be nyy bs gur bguref pna or erneenatrq gbb rkprcg gur svefg bar.)

Comment: @WeatherVane rot13(Tbbq pngpu! Gung vf cebonoyl bar bs gur raqf qrfpevorq va "V jvyy gnxr pner bs pbaarpgvat gur raqf, gurl qba'g unir gb pbaarpg gb gur obeqre.")

Comment: @cap rot13(fvapr gura V frr gur dhrfgvba fgngrf "lbh pnaabg punatr gur angheny funcr bs gur frtzragf" fb vs gurer zhfg or ng yrnfg sbhe raqf, gura creuncf nal ahzore bs hapbaarpgrq raqf?)

Comment: "a single contiguous path"

Comment: Question updated.  There must be a single path with two free ends.  One free end cannot connect to the border as already discovered.

Comment: But if one piece cannot connect to any other piece, and they can't be rearranged, and there must be a single contigous path with only two free ends, then there must be a trick to it.

Comment: @WeatherVane But it can connect to another piece. Just not both its ends simultaneously.

Comment: Of those two ends, one is connected to another piece, and the other is blocked. It isn't a free end.

Comment: "free" just means unconnected. That's also why the ends don't need to be at the border of the grid.

Comment: I confirm that the "free" end can be (and has to in one case) blocked by the wall of another segment.  I will be happy if you just fit everything inside all in one piece.

Comment: [tag:no-computers], I assume?

Comment: I thought about no-computers, but I myself solved it with a computer, and I won't be able to tell whether a computer was used.  In fact, I doubt there is a logical path to the solution, so feel free to use a computer.  However a logical step-by-step solution would definitely get the mark over a "here is the solution" answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found just one solution (apart from symmetries) with a C program.
Here is a rather crude drawing – I repaired the gut by hand.

> [image]
>
>  I reduced the search space by realising that the piece shaped like a nibbled donut has to be at one end – only one other piece can join to it.

Here is the C code. It looks reasonably simple, but only after two other attempts. The first was far too brutal, the second was abandoned when it got too complicated.

The final approach was to organise the pieces and their symmetries by the direction they are joined from. A route was then constructed by joining available pieces, that stays within the required area. To that end, the working board is large enough to contain any final position of the starting piece.

The code has a few 'bad practices' such as the use of globals and goto for convenience, but it did the job in a fraction of a second.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GRIDX   6
#define GRIDY   5
#define PIECES  10
#define LIMY    16
#define LIMX    16

typedef struct {
    int y1, x1; 
    int y2, x2;
} rec_t;
enum { N, E, S, W };
int dx[4] = { 0,  1,  0, -1 };
int dy[4] = { 1,  0, -1,  0 };
int board[LIMY][LIMX];
int result;
int used[PIECES];
int variants[PIECES] = { 0, 1, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4 };
// pieces organised by direction of entry, with symmetries
int shape[PIECES][4][4][4] = { // piece/dir/vari/detail(3 only)
    {   // dummy for 2x2 donut 0
        { {0, }, },
    },
    {   // 3x1 straight 1
        { {N, N, N,}, },     // North
        { {E, E, E,}, },     // East
        { {S, S, S,}, },     // South
        { {W, W, W,}, },     // West
    },
    {   // 3x1 one end bent 2
        { {N, N, W,}, {N, N, E,}, {E, E, E,}, {W, W, W,} },    // North
        { {E, E, S,}, {E, E, N,}, {N, N, N,}, {S, S, S,} },    // East
        { {S, S, W,}, {S, S, E,}, {E, E, E,}, {W, W, W,} },    // South
        { {W, W, N,}, {W, W, S,}, {N, N, N,}, {S, S, S,} },    // West
    }, 
    {   // 3x1 ends bent same way 3
        { {W, W, S,}, {E, E, S,}, },    // North
        { {N, N, W,}, {S, S, W,}, },    // East
        { {W, W, N,}, {E, E, N,}, },    // South
        { {N, N, E,}, {S, S, E,}, },    // West
    }, 
    {   // 3x1 ends bent diff way 4
        { {W, W, N,}, {E, E, N,}, },    // North
        { {N, N, E,}, {S, S, E,}, },    // East
        { {W, W, S,}, {E, E, S,}, },    // South
        { {N, N, W,}, {S, S, W,}, },    // West
    }, 
    {   // 2x2 zig-zag 5
        { {E, N, E,}, {W, N, W,}, },    // North
        { {N, E, N,}, {S, E, S,}, },    // East
        { {E, S, E,}, {W, S, W,}, },    // South
        { {N, W, N,}, {S, W, S,}, },    // West
    }, 
    {   // 2x2 elbow 6
        { {N, E, E,}, {N, W, W,}, },    // North
        { {E, N, N,}, {E, S, S,}, },    // East
        { {S, E, E,}, {S, W, W,}, },    // South
        { {W, N, N,}, {W, S, S,}, },    // West
    }, 
    {   // 2x2 u-turn 7
        { {E, S, S,}, {W, S, S,}, {N, E, S,}, {N, W, S,}, },    // North
        { {S, W, W,}, {N, W, W,}, {E, N, W,}, {E, S, W,}, },    // East
        { {E, N, N,}, {W, N, N,}, {S, W, N,}, {S, E, N,}, },    // South
        { {N, E, E,}, {S, E, E,}, {W, N, E,}, {W, S, E,}, },    // West
    }, 
    {   // 2x2 dogleg 8
        { {E, N, N,}, {W, N, N,}, {N, W, N,}, {N, E, N,}, },    // North
        { {N, E, E,}, {S, E, E,}, {E, N, E,}, {E, S, E,}, },    // East
        { {E, S, S,}, {W, S, S,}, {S, E, S,}, {S, W, S,}, },    // South
        { {S, W, W,}, {N, W, W,}, {W, N, W,}, {W, S, W,}, },    // West
    }, 
    {   // 2x2 u-bend 9
        { {E, S, E,}, {W, S, W,}, {W, N, E,}, {E, N, W,}, },    // North
        { {S, W, S,}, {N, W, N,}, {S, E, N,}, {N, E, S,}, },    // East
        { {W, N, W,}, {E, N, E,}, {E, S, W,}, {W, S, E,}, },    // South
        { {N, E, N,}, {S, E, S,}, {S, W, N,}, {N, W, S,}, },    // West
    }, 
};

void recur(int level, int sy, int sx, int dir, rec_t bound)
// fit next piece following the previous section at [sy][sx] in direction dir
// check and maintain overall bounds
{
    if(level >= PIECES) {
        // show solution
        for(int y=bound.y2; y>=bound.y1; y--) {
            for(int x=bound.x1; x<=bound.x2; x++) {
                printf("%c", 'A' + board[y][x]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        result++;
        return;
    }

    // check that a piece can connect
    rec_t limit = bound;
    if(limit.y1 > sy)    limit.y1 = sy;
    if(limit.y2 < sy)    limit.y2 = sy;
    if(limit.x1 > sx)    limit.x1 = sx;
    if(limit.x2 < sx)    limit.x2 = sx;
    if(limit.y2 - limit.y1 >= GRIDY) return;
    if(limit.x2 - limit.x1 >= GRIDX) return;
    if(board[sy][sx] >= 0) return;
    
    // try to fit each orientation of each piece
    int yy[3], xx[3];           // where placed
    for(int p=1; p<PIECES; p++) {
        if(used[p] == 0) {
            used[p] = 1;
            
            for(int v=0; v<variants[p]; v++) {
                // each orientation of piece
                rec_t lims = limit;
                int py = sy;
                int px = sx;
                int direc;
                
                // check the piece can be placed
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    if(i != 0)  {
                        // first section bounds was already checked
                        if(lims.y1 > py)    lims.y1 = py;
                        if(lims.y2 < py)    lims.y2 = py;
                        if(lims.x1 > px)    lims.x1 = px;
                        if(lims.x2 < px)    lims.x2 = px;
                        if(lims.y2 - lims.y1 >= GRIDY) goto nofit;
                        if(lims.x2 - lims.x1 >= GRIDX) goto nofit;
                        if(board[py][px] >= 0) goto nofit;
                    }
                    yy[i] = py;
                    xx[i] = px;
                    direc = shape[p][dir][v][i];
                    py += dy[direc];
                    px += dx[direc];
                }
                
                // place the piece
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                    board[ yy[i] ][ xx[i] ] = p;
                    
                // recurse with same direction as last segment
                recur(level + 1, py, px, direc, lims);
                
                // remove the piece
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
                    board[ yy[i] ][ xx[i] ] = -1;

                nofit: ;
            }
            used[p] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    memset(board, -1, sizeof board);
    rec_t bound = { 7, 7,  8, 8 };
    
    // set up the first piece in the middle
    board[8][7] =  0;   board[8][8] =  0;
    board[7][7] =  0;   board[7][8] = -1;
    recur(1, 7, 8, S, bound);
    
    // turn it clockwise
    board[8][7] =  0;   board[8][8] =  0;
    board[7][7] = -1;   board[7][8] =  0;
    recur(1, 7, 7, W, bound);
    
    printf("result=%d\n", result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: nicely done, and thank you for posting that just before i started writing code to solve it! you saved me a few hours of time today.